# installed puppet on a utility node

Tags: unix, configuration, puppeteer, puppet, redhat

I'm running a version 6 puppet on a utility node and when I try to connect to the puppet master from the puppet agent I get this error.

```
[root@utility ~]# puppet agent --test
Warning: Unable to fetch my node definition, but the agent run will continue:
Warning: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed: [unable to get certificate CRL for /CN=utility.example.com]
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Error: /File[/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/facts.d]: Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed: [unable to get certificate CRL for /CN=utility.example.com]
Error: /File[/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/facts.d]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet:///pluginfacts: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed: [unable to get certificate CRL for /CN=utility.example.com]
Info: Retrieving plugin
Error: /File[/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/lib]: Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed: [unable to get certificate CRL for /CN=utility.example.com]
Error: /File[/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/lib]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet:///plugins: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed: [unable to get certificate CRL for /CN=utility.example.com]
Info: Loading facts
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed: [unable to get certificate CRL for /CN=utility.example.com]
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

Also, the certificate on the puppet agent does not show on the puppet master when I run `puppet cert list --all`

```
Warning: `puppet cert` is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
   (location: /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/application.rb:370:in `run')
```

Comment: Note: `puppetserver ca` is the replacement for `puppet cert`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the agent is not issuing a certificate-signing request, it must already have a signed certificate.  But it seems not to be a certificate that the master recognizes, therefore the master will not accept it.  Possibly the agent does not accept the master's cert, either.

The master refusing service to an unrecognized agent is exactly what one would expect and want if an unauthorized node attempted to retrieve a catalog.  The agent refusing to complete a connection to the master is exactly what one would expect and want if an agent's catalog request were delivered to an imposter posing as the master.

But if an authorized agent is having such a problem requesting a catalog from a genuine master that it should recognize, then you have a trust failure.  This might happen, for example, if the agent's original master were replaced with a new one, or if Puppet were removed from the master and then re-installed.

If indeed that master has no cert for the agent in question, then you should be able to resolve the issue by shutting down the agent (if it is running as a daemon), then clearing out its certificates so that it generates a new one on its next run.  The Puppet docs describe [how this can be done](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6.17/ssl_regenerate_certificates.html#clear_regenerate_certs_for_agents) (you should need only step 3, "Clear and regenerate certs for Puppet agents", and only for the affected agent).

Comment: I got this error when trying to list the certificate on the master                       [root@utility ~]# puppetserver ca list --all
Fatal error when running action 'list'
  Error: Failed connecting to https://utility.example.com:8141/puppet-ca/v1/certificate_statuses/any_key
  Root cause: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed

Comment: @Mike, it sounds like a broader loss of trust, then.  Instead of just regenerating the agent cert, you probably need to go through the full procedure described on the doc page I already linked.

Comment: got this error also on puppet agentpuppet agent --test
Error: Could not request certificate: request https://puppet:8140//puppet-ca/v1/certificate/ca failed: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: sslv3 alert bad certificate
Exiting; failed to retrieve certificate and waitforcert is disabled

Comment: tried the full process also and I was still getting the same error

Comment: So the error message you're getting changed?  In the question you reported `puppet agent --test` emitting a different error message.

Comment: the first error is from the master while the one I just posted is from the agent

Comment: So you're saying that even running the agent on the machine that hosts the master fails? But the agent fails differently if you run it on other nodes?

Comment: To be clear: when I said "go through the full procedure", I meant the procedure into which my earlier link was pointing.  That starts at the "[Regenerate the CA and all certificates](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6.17/ssl_regenerate_certificates.html#regenerate_ca_and_all_certificates)" heading; there is a separate procedure preceding it, which you should ignore.  If that doesn't work then something obscure is going on, and a full reinstallation of all the server-side components would probably be in order (after which you will need to regenerate agent certs).

Comment: its two different machine, puppet agent is running on one machine while puppet master is running on another machine.what I'm trying to achieve is to make sure the two machine can connect successfully. Also, I just noticed I'm running puppet version 5.5.14 on the two machine